# Exposing docker to internet "Failed to complete tunnel connection"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ngrok

I'm using this https://github.com/wernight/docker-ngrok , so that my dockerize app will expose to internet. I added it to my docker-compose, but when I up my container I get this error "Failed to complete tunnel connection". when I want to access my app I do it like this myapp.local and it works find because I set up windows host. when I access like this http://localhost I see this , I noticed I cannot access using localhost that's why I used windows host.

[image]

Here is my docker-compose

```
web:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: webcontainer
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/myapp
      - ./myapp.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf
    expose:
      - 9000
    external_links:
      - php
      - db
  ngrok:
    image: wernight/ngrok
    links:
      - web
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
```

[image]